# Android "The publisher cannot purchase the item"

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm not testing my in app purchase !

I have download my app from google play store and I still can't buy any of my In App purchase within the application.

I have the following error : "The publisher cannot purchase the item".

All my In App purchase are also valid and active.
I'm using the same google account than in my google play developer console.

I have read on google that it's normal that developer can't buy it's own items in testing mode (alpha or beta) but here i'm using the official version and I still can't do it !! (It's my first android application)

What did I do wrong ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

if you have the same account configured on the device (the one which you are using for developer console) make sure it is removed. Google Play will allow switching between all google accounts added on device. Also, before removing try switching directly in google play first to an account that is not your developer account and then do the purchase. If that doesn't work you'll probably need to remove the developer account for the device if you want to make a purchase fro your own app.